# How to make an app minimize itself after some time?

Tags: windows-10, command-line-arguments, delay

Is there an argument to specify for an app to **minimize** itself after being launched **after a certain delay** in Windows?

I made a .bat file to be able to launch multiple apps with one launcher, I provided the `/min` argument for some of them so they start minimized, but I can't seem to find an argument to specify a delay after what time they should minimize themselves (in seconds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```bat
Powershell -WindowStyle style [name_script_file] ;exit
```

You can also use aliases **`-NoP`** and **`W`**:

```bat
Powershell -NoP -W style [name_script_file] ;exit
```

-NoP -WindowStyle

```bat
-WindowStyle
    Sets the window style to Normal, Minimized, Maximized or Hidden.
```

```bat
@echo off 

rem :: do some tasks...
       "%__APPDIR__%Ping.exe" 1.1.1.1 -n 1 | Find "TTL"

rem :: apply timeout/delay execution...
       "%__APPDIR__%TimeOut.exe" -t 2 

rem :: use PowerShell to change your Windows -WindowStyle to Minimized
       "%__APPDIR__%\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe" -NoP -W Minimized ;exit

rem :: do some more tasks...
       "%__APPDIR__%Ping.exe" 1.1.1.1 -n 1 | Find "TTL"

rem :: apply more (if needs) TimeOut/delay execution...
       "%__APPDIR__%Timeout.exe" -t 2 

rem :: use PowerShell to change back your windows -WindowStyle to Normal
       "%__APPDIR__%\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe" -NoP -W Normal ;exit
```

You can use the **[timhetzel](https://community.spiceworks.com/people/timhetzel)** **[answer](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1710213-hide-a-powershell-console-window-when-running-a-script)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PowerShell** to control your opened desktop windows.

Use the VexasoftCmdlet [Set-WindowState](https://www.vexasoft.com/pages/set-windowstate) to control the state (min, max etc.) of your window. It must be used in conjunction with the Get-Window cmdlet.

For example, with this piece of code you can minimize your opened PS window:

```
Get-Window powershell | Set-WindowState -Minimize
```

You can use the [Start-Sleep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7) Cmdlet to pause your script for example for 15 seconds

```
Start-Sleep -s 15
```