# How to minimize a running bat without using another one for that action

Tags: batch, windows-11

I am using a Window Manager program that won't run at logon even though the "start when Windows starts" box is checked.

I put it in the startup folder and it starts when I logon but the window remains open until I manually close it.

I want it to start the program and have it minimized to the tray automatically, and I have created 2 .bat files, one opens the program and the other closes it to the tray.

I have tried many different scripts but I don't know how to create a script that runs both steps in the process.  When I place both batch scripts in one .bat only the first script is executed.

I have tried the popular 3rd party softwares but none of them effects the program.

Can anyone help me with a solution that will run both scripts in one .bat file?

I've worked on this for two days and I cannot find a solution. I can't get the `call` command to work and task sechduler dosen't help.

Comment: Create a 3rd .bat that would call them in order, and maybe use `|` or `&` accordingly?

Comment: call the programs using `start title program` or use `cmd /c program params` This will instruct to run the program, but immediately go to the next statement. Or with a 3rd batch, use `call batch1` `call batch2` to run a batch and continue to the next line immediately.

Comment: You use 2 bat's to, one starts a program, and other runs after to minimize that program? "start /min notepad.exe" from single bat doesnt work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an app minimize itself after some time?](https://superuser.com/questions/1541480/how-to-make-an-app-minimize-itself-after-some-time)